# what are the limits for IMG_FILTER_CONTRAST imagefilter

Tags: php, image, gd, contrast, imagefilter

I am working on php gd image filters. Grayscale, Brightness, Negate, Colorize works well, but trying `imagefilter($img, IMG_FILTER_CONTRAST, $level);`
I found it somewhat ambiguous. The level limits for contrast are not clearly  mentioned at the [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagefilter.php). Putting level values above 255 and below -255 also produces some result. Same is the case with `imagefilter($img, IMG_FILTER_SMOOTH, $level);`
So, can someone please clear that what is the finite range for contrast level in php gd..
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2):

According to the comments in the [imagefilter manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagefilter.php#72329):

```
IMG_FILTER_CONTRAST
-100 = max contrast, 0 = no change, +100 = min contrast (note the direction!)
```